# how to setup a uniqueid in ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am learning RavenDB and getting familiar with how things work. One thing I do not understand is how to save the id that raven creates to a property.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; } //This will be null when I save object to DB I want it to be same as generated
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSaving()
{
    using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        var user = new User { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
        session.Store(user);
        session.SaveChanges(); //I want that property to save that id that raven created: Users/65
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the default convention in Raven for finding the identity property is "Id" and is case-sensitive.  Try renaming your property to Id, rather than ID.

Answer (score 1):

Look again.  Immediately after calling `session.Store(user)` you will find that the `ID` property is already set for you.  Even before `SaveChanges()` is called.

**Update**

Sorry, I didn't notice the casing of your property.  Raven's default convention is to look for a property called "Id" - which is case sensitive.  If you want a different convention, you can  change raven's defaults:

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = x => x.Name == "ID";
```

You can read more about the default conventions [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/connecting-to-a-ravendb-datastore#conventions)

Comment: Then Why is the actual property is set to null in the document?